# Optional variables in Python

Tags: python

do you guys know if there exists a Python equivalent to boost::optional in C++ (or std::optional since C++11: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional), i.e. a library that handles *semantically optional* variables?

I know how to implement it myself or use the other solutions (like `foo = (bar, True)` which I find ugly and unreadable). Just curious if there is an existing solution.

Comment: Why not just use `None` to represent an absent value?

Comment: When you say optional. Is what you _really_ mean is the [**maybe monad**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)#The_Maybe_monad) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Optional variables, a limited form of algebraic typing, are primarily useful in statically typed languages. In dynamically typed languages like Python, there's no real need for them. As arshajii said, you can use `None` (or, if you prefer, any other sentinel you'd like) to represent an absent value. You then just check whether the variable has the expected type or not.

Comment: c++ optional and None default value has a real different semantics. Supposing the value I want to store in an optional variable can already hold the None type, how can I check if this optional variable has been set ?

Comment: @etham Well, ideally you'd fix your overly complicated data model. But if you insisted on it, you could simply use (for instance) a one-element tuple to wrap the value.

Comment: You are right. A language with too much features prevent us from having a nice design. I fixed my data model ;)